# Ember.js : cannot make one-way bindings work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a template who is iterating on a list of numbers and create a form. I don't want the changes made to the forms propagated to the underlying values, therefore, i am using a one way-binding.

Unfortunately, it doesnt't seems to work : [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qayafiwu/15/edit)

Thanks you a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the Binding is setup at the "list" level, so the oneWay binding does not apply to specific items and their properties.

Instead of a oneWay binding, you can create a computed property which generates a new copy of your list.

Comment: How would i create a new copy ? Can you provide an example ?